# Two queries with equal results takes vastly different time to execute?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm currently using redshift. I was trying to execute a query to calculate a column called `id_number` (data type INTEGER) from a VARCHAR column called `id` to speed up further queries using `id_number` instead of `id`.

Here is the first query I tried :

```
select rank() over (order by id) id_number, id, sid1 ,sid2
from table
limit 10000
```

However, noticing that this query was taking quite some time, I tried the next query:

```
with A as(
 select id, sid1, sid2 
 from table
 limit 10000
)
select rank() over (order by id) id_number, id, sid1 ,sid2
from A
```

which was over in a flash.

How was it that the second query took such less time to execute, while the two queries seem to do the exact same thing?

If it is because of the positions of `limit 10000`, how did the position of `limit` contribute to the difference in execution time?

Comment: How many lines does table actually have? In the first query you execute rank() over the whole table and limit it afterwards. In the second you limit it on a simple select and then call rank(). In second case you cut off results before calling rank().

Comment: `In the second you limit it on a simple select and then call rank(). In second case you cut off results before calling rank().`

Don't they mean the same, limiting (cutting off) before calling rank()?

Comment: My knowledge is that the limit is applied after the `select ... from`, which in first case is after the rank was executed as part of the select. In second case the `select ... from` is limited and on the result the rank is called. If I am wrong, please let me know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two queries are quite different.

The first one has to sort the complete table to get the `rank()` and then emits the first 10000 rows of the result (with no particular ordering enforced).

The second one selects 10000 rows (without a particular ordering enforced) and then sorts those to calculate `rank()` on them.

If the table is significantly larger than 10000 rows, it is unsurprising that the first query, which has to sort it all, is much slower.

Look at the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output to understand this better.